# A question about complete graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Please,could you help at the following question?

Show that if G is a simple graph that has at least 6 peaks,then G contains a cycle with length 3 or the complement of G contains a cycle with length 3.

I tried induction,but it isn't working.I'm completely stuck.

Comment: What kind of induction were you trying to do? All the numbers in the question are fixed.

Comment: Why?n is moving,n>=6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph on 6 vertices.  Pick one vertex $v$, and think about the edges connected to it.  There are five other vertices, so either there are at least 3 edges incident to $v$ in $G$, or there are at least 3 edges incident to it in the complement $G^c$.  Now consider the three vertices that $v$ is connected to in either $G$ or $G^c$.  Think about edges between these vertices and whether they force there to be a cycle in $G$ or $G^c$.

Just as a side note, this problem is equivalent to showing that the Ramsey number $R(3,3)$ is at most 6.

Comment: Why are there three vertices incident with a vertex v in a simple graph?And why does that show me that there is a 3-cycle in G or Gc?

Comment: Please,could you answer me,Christian Gaetz?

Comment: There aren't necessarily 3 vertices incident to $v$ in $G$, but if there aren't then there must be 3 vertices incident to $v$ in $G^c$ (each one of the five possible edges occurs in either $G$ or $G^c$, so at least three must occur in one of these graphs).  I'll leave the conclusion to you, write down some possible cases and show that you always get a cycle in either $G$ or $G^c$.